# Prove the convergence of the sequence given by the recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I have the following problem:

> Let us $v_1^{(0)}, v_2^{(0)}, v_3^{(0)} > 0$. Define the sequence
> $$ v_1^{(k+1)} = \dfrac{3}{ \dfrac{2}{v_1^{(k)} + v_3^{(k)}} + \dfrac{4}{v_1^{(k)} + v_2^{(k)}} } $$
> $$ v_2^{(k+1)} = \dfrac{4}{ \dfrac{4}{v_1^{(k)} + v_2^{(k)}} + \dfrac{2}{v_2^{(k)} + v_3^{(k)}} } $$
> $$ v_3^{(k+1)} = \dfrac{1}{ \dfrac{2}{v_1^{(k)} + v_3^{(k)}} + \dfrac{2}{v_2^{(k)} + v_3^{(k)}} } $$
> Prove that the sequence $\{v^{(k)}\}_k = \{(v_1^{(k)}, v_2^{(k)}, v_3^{(k)})\}_k$ converges.

Most of the proof methods that I know require knowledge of the limit of the sequence. In this case, it is difficult for me to guess what the expression for the sequence limit should be. Without knowing the limit, it would be possible to prove that the sequence is fundamental, but the calculations look too cumbersome.

I tried some numerical experiments and it looks like the sequence converges for any non-zero $v_1^{(0)}, v_2^{(0)}$ and $v_3^{(0)}$. In this case, for different starting values ​​$v_1^{(0)}, v_2^{(0)}$ and $v_3^{(0)}$, the sequence converges to different limit points, however, all limit points lie on a straight line with direction vector $(0.5333965 , 0.8173959 , 0.21760542)$. But this fact looks clear from the form of the recurrence formula.

I tried to calculate the Jacobian of the recurrence mapping at the limit points. Predictably, all eigenvalues ​​are less than 1 except one, which is 1. The eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue equal to 1 is $(0.5333965 , 0.8173959 , 0.21760542)$. This result also looks predictable.

Another interesting observation that I got from numerical experiments is that the ratio
$$ \dfrac{\|v^{(k+1)} - v^{*}\|_\infty}{\|v^{(k)} - v^{*}\|_\infty}$$
stabilizes fairly quickly as $k$ increases. Here $v^{*}$ denotes the limit of the sequence. An example of $ \dfrac{\|v^{(k+1)} - v^{*}\|_\infty}{\|v^{(k)} - v^{*}\|_\infty}$ ratio values ​​when running from a random point.

$$0.08030587438292239$$
$$0.2095128000211839$$
$$0.31076298843195116$$
$$0.35864703173973156$$
$$0.35707344342023817$$
$$0.3565920036480916$$
$$0.3564327245958076$$
$$0.3563787026001393$$
$$0.3563602243686815$$
$$0.35635388477426155$$

However, these are all numerical experiments, I do not have any rigorous evidence. I welcome any advice, ideas, observations, or references to the literature. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Personally, my first try, which might well fail, would be to strive to express $~\left[v_r\right]^{(k)}~$ in terms of $~\left[v_1\right]^{(0)}, ~\left[v_2\right]^{(0)}, ~\left[v_3\right]^{(0)}~$ for each $~r \in \{1,2,3\}~$.  In making the attempt, my primary weapon would be **elbow grease**.  Simply manually compute the corresponding variables,  for $~k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}~$ and see where it leads.